# PHP Getting error for $page = $_GET['page'];

Tags: php

This is my entire code. Shared to you.

This is my error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in /export/home/dynamic/index.php on line 20
```

I can't seem to figure out why I keep getting this error. It is not the first time, I've suspected that it is the array but I don't know what to do with it.

It's suppose to make a dynamic change page to my website. 
I've had errors before where I make a global varible like `$page = $_GET['page'];`

I am open to any kind of answer and I am greatful to every single on of them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Header<br />
<nav>
<a href="index.php?page=index">INDEX</a>
<a href="index.php?page=page1">Startsida</a>
<a href="index.php?page=page2">Anteckningar</a>
<a href="index.php?page=page3">Kontakt</a>
<!-- <a href="index.php?page=faq">FAQ</a> -->
</nav></header>

<div id="content">
<?php 

// Place the value from ?page=value in the URL to the variable $page. 
$page = $_GET['page']; 

// Create an array of the only pages allowed. 
$pageArray = array( 
       'index', 
       'page1', 
       'page2', 
       'page3', 
       'faq' 
         ); 

// If there is no page set, include the default main page. 

if (!$page) { 
  include('pages/index.php'); 
} 

// Is $page in the array? 
$inArray = in_array($page, $pageArray); 

// If so, include it, if not, emit error. 
 if ($inArray == true) { 
  include('pages/'. $page .'.php'); 
}else { 
  echo 'Umm tisk tisk. You should not be messing with things.'; 
} 
?> 
</div>

<footer>Footer</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

IT IS SOLVED!
Thanks to hek2mgl my code now works properly.

I want to thank the rest for submitting your answers to my problem. I owe you guys.

Comment: at first you should always  check existence of $_GET['page'] variable, using  isset() - http://de2.php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check if `page` was transmitted via GET vars:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    // set proper default value if it was not set
    $page = 'index';
}
```

In the next step you need to check if `$page` contains a proper value:

```
if(!in_array($page, $pages)) {
    die('page was not found');
}
```

Comment: But that's what i've done here. 

// Is $page in the array? 
   $inArray = in_array($page, $pageArray); 

// If so, include it, if not, emit error. 
   if ($inArray == true) { 
      include('pages/'. $page .'.php'); 
   }else { 
      echo 'Umm tisk tisk. You should not be messing with things.'; 
   }

Comment: Holy moly! It worked! :D Thank you!

Using 

if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    // set proper default value if it was not set
    $page = 'index';
}

worked :) Thank's alot

Comment: glad that it helped :) Yeah, in PHP, you need to make sure that an array index exists before accessing it.

Comment: I am very glad that it worked :) Thank you once again.

If it isnt any inconvenience, could you please link to a page that explains that further more? :)

Comment: Seems about right, thank you for your time :) You've been very helpful and I am greatful for every single answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a value that doesn't exist. Before using a $_GET you should be checking that it exists.

Use `isset($_GET['page'];)`

Comment: Thank you for submitting your answer. 
My problem is now solved :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because `'page'` is not an existing index in `$_GET`. You can check that it is first

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : "";
```

or you can silence the notice

```
$page = @$_GET['page'];
```

afterwards, just check if the page is a known page

```
$page = in_array($page, $knownPages) ? $page : "index";
```

Comment: Thank you for submitting your answer. My problem is now solved :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$p = array("Home", "About", "Hosting", "VPS","GameServer","Contact");
     if(isset($_GET['page']) AND in_array($_GET['page'],$p))
        {
            include('pages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php');
        }else{
            include('pages/home.php');
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just little upgrage to previous answer

```
<?php 

$p = array("Home", "About", "Hosting", "VPS","GameServer","Contact");

if ((isset($_GET['page']) || !empty($_GET['page'])) && in_array($_GET['page'], $p))

    {
        include('pages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php');

}else{

        include('pages/home.php');
    }

?>
```